# use python with TDengine database but got bind params error

Tags: python, database, time-series, tdengine

It's quite simple to insert data into TDengine database but still got errors.

`use conn.statement("insert info cache_record values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")`

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ehigh/work/PythonWorker/Worker/HGSocialSecurity/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    curd.bind_insert([
  File "/home/ehigh/work/PythonWorker/Worker/HGSocialSecurity/curd/cache_table.py", line 15, in bind_insert
    stmt = conn.statement("insert info cache_record values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
  File "/home/ehigh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taos/connection.py", line 103, in statement
    taos_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql)
  File "/home/ehigh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taos/cinterface.py", line 626, in taos_stmt_prepare
    raise StatementError(msg=taos_stmt_errstr(stmt), errno=res)
  File "/home/ehigh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taos/cinterface.py", line 656, in taos_stmt_errstr
    err = c_char_p(_libtaos.taos_stmt_errstr(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /lib/libtaos.so: undefined symbol: taos_stmt_errstr
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess probably you are running an older version TDengine with the library doesn't provide that function interface.